# IE strange behaviour while submitting a form in an iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, file-upload

I'm trying to realize system for submitting files without full page rerendering. In order to do this I've created a form with input (`type = file`) in it and a mechanism for dynamic iframe creating/appending. After the iFrame is created and appended, I set `target` attribute of the form on the iframe.

In other browsers this mechanism works perfectly, but IE instead of loading content into the iFrame propose me to save input data like a file. What is incorrectly in my logic? Perhaps this is a problem of dynamic creation of iFrame or something wrong with configuration of my IE?

Here is the sources:

```
createIFrame: function(appendToSelector) {
  var nameWthId = "uploadTarget" + (new Date().getTime());
  var iFrame = $("<iframe style='display:none;'></iframe>");
  iFrame.attr('id', nameWthId);
  iFrame.attr('name', nameWthId);
  iFrame.appendTo(appendToSelector);
  return nameWthId;
}

fileUploadManual: function(dom) {
  var iFrameName = context.createIFrame(dom + " .manual-upload-file");
  $(dom + " .fileUploadForm")[0].target = iFrameName;
  $(dom + " .fileUploadForm")[0].action = config.post;
  $(dom + " #" + iFrameName).load(function(ev) {
    //some logic
  })
}
```

Comment: does it work without an iframe (not setting the target)? IE forcing to download seems something else than an iframe issue but like there's something wrong with the response mime-type etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8151138/ie-jquery-form-multipart-json-response-ie-tries-to-download-response) question.

You have to return a `"text/html"` mime type for your response.