# Fine Uploader and ServiceStack setting Response headers

Tags: javascript, file-upload, servicestack, fine-uploader

I am trying to use ServiceStack as an endpoint of Fine Uploader to upload some files. Because of a nasty behaviour with IE if the response is set to content type json/application ie prompts to download the rseponse as reported here:

[IE tries to download json response while submitting jQuery multipart form data containing file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8151138/ie-jquery-form-multipart-json-response-ie-tries-to-download-response)

How can I force ServiceStack to respond as text/plain. I am trying this:

```
 public class UploadFileService : Service
    {
        [AddHeader(ContentType = "text/plain")]
        public object Any(UploadFile request)
        {
            foreach (var uploadedFile in base.RequestContext.Files)
            {
                var test = uploadedFile.FileName;
            }
            return new UploadFileResponse{ Success = true};
        }
    }
```

But Service stack when using the endpoint:

```
/api/UploadFile?format=json
```

Still returns the content type as application/json

Any Ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to return a `plain/text` string, you need to also return a string [as seen in this example](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.UseCases/blob/master/HelloWorld/Global.asax.cs#L75). Because it's a POCO object you want to serialize it first (assuming JSON):

```
public class UploadFileService : Service
{
    [AddHeader(ContentType = "text/plain")]
    public object Any(UploadFile request)
    {
        foreach (var uploadedFile in base.RequestContext.Files)
        {
            var test = uploadedFile.FileName;
        }
        var dto = new UploadFileResponse { Success = true };
        return dto.ToJson();           
    }
}
```

Otherwise you can just return a string literal directly, e.g:

```
return "{Success:true}";
```